# C++ Return two large std::vector

Tags: c++11, return-value

I have a function that needs to return a pair of std vectors (different dimension). I could also return a pair or tuple. What I want to avoid is copying the whole vector just to return it.

Will something like this code :

```
return make_pair(vec1, vec2_diffDim);
```

Duplicate the vectors or will it use a reference?

Comment: I would recommend exploring `return make_pair(std::move(vec1), std::move(vec2_diffDim));`.

Comment: I don't know if its appropriate to your situation but you could possibly pass the vectors into the function by reference rather than return them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `vec1` and `vec2_diffDim` are variables local to your function, you should use `make_pair(std::move(vec1), std::move(vec2_diffDim))`. `make_pair<T1,T2>` accepts universal references of types `T1` and `T2`. However, since only rvalues can bind to the rvalue reference overload, `make_pair(vec1, vec2_diffDim)` will bind to the version that makes a copy of both arguments. The copy of the returned `pair` can be elided. So, you are guaranteed that it will be moved at least.